# Line chart function pulling out data from different columns

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I trying to create a function to draw a simple line chart with CO2 emission figures for different cities. In my dataset, every column is a city and every row is a year, so the figures refer to the CO2 released to the atmosphere for every year in that place.

```
function lineChart(city){

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date / time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
    .y("function(d) { return y(d."+city+"); }");

;}

lineChart("london");
```

I know the code is incomplete but I pasted this bit to let you know what I want to do. I want to draw different graphs for each city by calling the function with the city as the variable. I tried with this `.y("function(d) { return y(d."+city+"); }");` but it is not working.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: `.y(function(d) { return y(d[city]); });`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `"` around the `"function(d) { return y(d."+city+"); }"` -- that tells javascript to interpret the text `function(d) { return y(d.` and `); }` as a string, giving a `y` attribute of `function(d) { return y(d.london); }`. You want to perform the function, rather than just quote it.

To access the data for the city, you need to access

```
d['london']
```

from the object `d` (it can also be written as `d.london`). Since `city` is a variable storing the name of the current city, you can do this using

```
d[city]
```

The whole line is thus

```
.y(function(d) { return y(d[city]); });
```